# 1対多の関係をもつモデルをDBの保存する際のテストをrspecで書きたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

今railsでTwitterライクなwebアプリを作っていてユーザーが投稿した際にリダイレクトされるかのテストを行いたいのですが次のようなエラーが出ます。

```
1) PostsController POST #create parameter is reasonable redirect user page
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to user

   Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
   Response body:
```

FactoryBotに`association :user, factory: :user`と記述を加えてみましたが、エラー文は変わりませんでした。
また、エラーが出てるテストの一つ上の"is registered"をコメントアウトしてみたら何故かテストが通ったのですが、理由が分かりません。

以上、もし両方のテストが通る方法が分かる方がいたらよろしくお願いします。

---

posts_controllr_spec.rb

```
  describe "POST #create" do
context "parameter is reasonable" do
  let(:valid_attributes) {
    FactoryBot.attributes_for(:post)
  }

  it "is registered" do
    expect {
      post :create, params: { user_id: user.id, post: valid_attributes }
    }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "redirect user page" do
    post :create, params: { user_id: user.id, post: valid_attributes }
    expect(response).to redirect_to user
  end
end
```

users.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :admin_user, class: User do
    name 'Alice'
    email 'test@gmail.com'
    intro 'rubyなう'
    password 'Testtesttest'
    admin true
  end

  factory :user, class: User do
    name 'Bob'
    email 'test@gmail.com'
    intro 'rubyなう'
    password 'Testtesttest'
  end
end
```

posts.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post, class: Post do
    content 'a' * 140
    image Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/tokyo.jpg'))
  end
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = 'succeed in posting'
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

追記
controller#saveのrender 'new'の直前で@post.errors.full_messagesの中身を調べたら次のようになっていました。

```
[2] pry(#<PostsController>)> @post.errors.full_messages
=> ["Image can't be blank", "Image Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image?"]
```

Comment: テスト時に save に失敗して、 render new のところが実行されたりしてませんか？

Comment: その通りです。redirect_to userをrender_template 'new'に変更すると通ります。

Comment: saveに失敗した理由を出力させて、質問に追記（編集）することはできますか？

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi 追記しましたのでご確認して頂けたら幸いです。

Comment: 何かしらの理由で画像がうまく保存できない（？）ようですね。（申し訳ないですが、はっきりしたことは現段階ではまだ私には言えないですが）

Comment: @shingo.nakanishiそうですね。調べても中々出てこなくて困ってます。。。